# How can I interpret "typical both of a particular class"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> We were, I think, **typical both of a particular class** of pre-war
> Germans and, by contrast, of the post-war country at large. On both
> sides our family was old, well established and, notwithstanding the
> wrecked economy, well off.

I don't know how can I receive the bolded part since 'typical' and 'particular' sound opposite to me.

Comment: Typical and particular are more similar than opposite. Typical here means we were like an average kind of rich German, a representative of that group. Particular means this specific kind of German.

Comment: We were [**almost certainly**] members of a certain class (call it set S1) of Germans that existed before the war.  And we were typical members of S1.

Comment: It's either missing yet another comma, an *ly*, another *of*, or either *of* or *both* is in the wrong spot.

Comment: A quote from *Hitler's Forgotten Children: My Life Inside the Lebensborn* by Ingrid Von Oelhafen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whatever the link you make between ***typical*** and ***particular***, you do not need to be worried that they clash in your sentence. ***particular*** simply modifies one of the categories "we were typical of". You can simplify and say:

> We were, I think, typical both of A and, by contrast, of B.

where A is

> a ***particular*** (certain, specific) class of pre-war Germans

We were representative of a ***particular*** class, not of ***any*** class.

Answer (score 2):

Typical means

> having the distinctive qualities of a particular type of person or thing.

You have a certain class of pre-war Germans consisting of a group of people with certain characteristic. The writer is a typical example of those people, as well as the postwar country at large.

Comment: This is about the writer's family rather than the writer herself (she - Ingrid Von Oelhafen - was born during WWII).